# Folder failed to move while installing haxm

Tags: android, android-studio

I just tried install haxm by clicking sdk manager and install it from there but I got the below message.

```
Failed to rename directory E:\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager to E:\sdk\temp\ExtraPackage.old01.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

What is the reason? 
The second folder contains haxm_windows_r6_0_1 and its setup file. I cannot understand why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the required authorization. Close Android studio and run it as administrator.